# Localization in MVC6 RequiredAttribute for SqlLocalization

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get localization working for the required attribute in an MVC6 ViewModel.

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "err_uname_required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(MPSHouse.Localization.SqlLocalization))]
```

I am using a custom IStringLocalizer and IStringLocalizerFactory which is working, but do not know how to get it to work in the required attribute.

I am new to MVC and have been using WebForms until now, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to look at the documentation: https://docs.asp.net/en/1.0.0-rc2/fundamentals/localization.html#dataannotations-localization

Comment: I have added AddDataAnnotationsLocalization() and most of them are working. Compare does not work. It is also looking for the same string for all validations on the one field, such as required and minlength of user name will look for RegisterViewMode.UserName. I am using rc1 until the tooling is complete for visual studio.